# Python Multiprocesssing: When i submit a list of objects to ProcessPoolExecutor, is a copy or a reference submitted?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I try to parallelize a part of a huge project. I got a lattice consistent of points and I perform a calculation at each individual point of the lattice. To speed up the calculation I want to subdivide the points of the lattice into different sublists and perform the calculations on individual processes via a ProcessPoolExecutor. However, if I pass the list to ProcessPoolExecutor it seems like the list gets copied and no reference is passed.

A minimal version of my code is as follows:

```
from time import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class Lattice():

    def __init__(self, rndl):
        self.Points = []
        for val in rndl:
            P = Point(val)
            self.Points.append(P)

class Point():

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def calculate(self, it = 100):
        for i in range(it):
            some_tmp_value = self.val**(1.0/10)
            some_tmp_value = some_tmp_value**(1.0/10)
        self.val -= 1  #update values

def do_calculation_ser_2(lattice, it = 100):
    workers = 2
    splitted_list = [lattice.Points[i::workers] for i in range(workers)]
    for sublist in splitted_list:
        for P in sublist:
            P.calculate(it)

def par_calc_helper(sublist, it):
    for i,P in enumerate(sublist):
        P.calculate(it)
    return None
    
def do_calculation_par_partitioning(lattice, it):
    workers = 2 #define number of subprocesses
    #split list in chunks
    splitted_list = [lattice.Points[i::workers] for i in range(workers)]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = workers) as executor:
        for i, sublist in enumerate(splitted_list):
            future = executor.submit(par_calc_helper, sublist, it)

def check_calc(lattice, rndl):
    for i,(P, val_rnd) in enumerate(zip(lattice.Points, rndl)):
        error = False
        P.val += 1
        if P.val != val_rnd:
            print("ERROR - Calulation gone wrong")
            error = True
            break
    if not error:
        print("Calculation gone right")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_iter = 2*8
    rndl = [4,4,4,4]
    lat = Lattice(rndl)
    do_calculation_ser_2(lat, max_iter)
    check_calc(lat, rndl)
    do_calculation_par_partitioning(lat, max_iter)
    check_calc(lat, rndl)
```

Output:

```
Calculation gone right
ERROR - Calulation gone wrong
```

The lattice class is just a container for all points. The point class has just a value and a calculate method. The for loop inside the calculate method is just that it takes some time to execute the function. The result is the point vale decremented by 1 so i can check easily if the calculation is done right later on.

Then the *do_calculation_ser_2* method is the serial version of the calculation. I split the point list into a number of sublists and iterate over them and perform the calculation. I know the splitting is useless here, but I wanted to keep it similar to the parallel version, so I can tackle errors better.

The *do_calculation_par_partitioning* method is used to parallelize my calculation. First, I subdivide the points of my lattice into sublists. Then I use the helper function to iterate over the sublist and pass the helper function along with the sublist to my ProcessPoolExecutor.

Lastly, the *check_calc* function is used to check if the calculation is done right and it increments the point values again by one to get the lattice from before.

As a test, I just initiate 4 points with the value 4 and perform the calculation. When I try to run it, the serial version works perfectly fine. However, the parallel version does not work for the points. The calculation methods are called correctly (I can see that if I insert print statements inside the methods), but the resulting value is not set correctly and stays 4 instead of the expected 3.

I assume that passing a list of objects towards a ProcessPoolExecutor will copy the objects in the list instead of just referencing them (as in the serial version). Is this the case? If yes, how do I pass a list of objects without copying them each time? (Would be bad for really large calculations).
Would passing a copy of the lists and replacing the main lists with the result of the calculations work best or is there a better way?

If my approach is completely wrong and you got better ideas to do this in Python please let me know.

Comment: I can see that you are using from concurrent feature, I dont see any multiprocessing here. I think should have some more basics about python concurrcny. please reade through https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Comment: Yes but I use the ProcessPoolExecutor, as described in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) the ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing module of python.

Comment: I studied the topic quite recently and this is the part I don't understand so that's why I'm asking the question. I did understand the differences between threading/multiprocessing however, I'm not sure how to handle my problem best. Your provides no information related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are knocking your head on a process boundary... More seriously, the ProcessPoolExecutor starts a number of worker *processes*, serializes the value that will be passed to them and pass the serialized value in a pipe. Then each worker does it work in its own memory zone and the master process data cannot be updated.

A possible way is that each worker returns its modified list (which will again be serialized) and the parent concatenates them. Alternatively, the multiprocessing module provides shared types using shared memory, but it comes at the price of additional synchronization. In your use case, I would probably just return the modified lists.

Comment: Okay, so that's what I assumed. So as I understand it copy my list to the worker processes. So could I used shared memory to work on parts of my list. Let's say for this example process 1 to do the calculation of point 1,2 and process 2 to do the calculation of point 3,4? I'm working on a bigger script and copying lists all the time would not be sufficient.

Comment: IMHO, it should be benchmarked. As an alternative way, you could also have a look to memory mapped files which can easily be shared across process boundaries. You will have to use explicit synchronization, but it can be a good point because you can only use the strictly required synchronization points.

Comment: Thank you I will try to implement both versions then and check which one suits it better.